# How to use Java client/server classes correctly

Tags: java, class, client-server

Are client and server classes done in the same .java file or separate ones, and if they're in separate files, then do I import them like CSS -> HMTL.

If this is too beginner of a question, can someone just help me on what to search in order to get the right articles.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Thanks, it's my first question here. I cleaned it up.

Comment: @Qix Yeah, I know. My javascript skills are actually a lot better than my Java, but I'm in an online Java class, with a teacher who just e-mails back that I need to Google it.

Comment: I think your teacher might be on to something.

Comment: What are you googling?

Comment: "client server class," "java import server class", etc. I'm sure that I'm just making a stupid search mistake and just missing a keyword or phrase.

Comment: I'm also getting a lot of websites on how to import Java libraries/directories.

Comment: In that case, Jared's answer is correct. You're misunderstanding how classes work; Java classes have no knowledge of "server" or "client".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how you've asked the question, I believe the misunderstanding may be within the definition of a class. A "client class" (as far as I can tell) means a class that exists in the client application. A "server class" would be one that exists within the server application.

Look into client-server models and what the class is asking you to do may become more apparent.

[Client-Server Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

> The client–server characteristic describes the relationship of cooperating programs in an application. The server component provides a function or service to one or many clients, which initiate requests for such services.

A client and a server are (*usually*) two separate applications. You would build two different applications that interface with each other through some communication protocol.

Once you understand the difference between a server and a client, the distinction between a server class and a client class would become apparent.

The short answer to the classes question: in the vast majority of scenarios, client and server code is done in different classes (and different programs). There are certain types of architecture that will have both client and server logic in the same codebase (peer-to-peer applications being one example), but you will have to research the architecture and make a decision based on the assignment itself.

As for imports: yes. The concept of an import exists in the Java language and is used to allow you to use a class defined in one file in another file.

[Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) is documentation from the Oracle website that provides additional information on imports.

> To use a public package member from outside its package, you must do one of the following:
>
> ```
> Refer to the member by its fully qualified name
> Import the package member
> Import the member's entire package
> ```

If you're new to Java and programming, check out the [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) trail on the Oracle page (as well as the other documentation).